# Grunt livereload with node.js application

Tags: node.js, yeoman, gruntjs, livereload

I have written an application in Node.js (with Express & socket.io) and **I would like to use Grunt to compile my client-side stuff with livereload while developing and being connected to Node.js application. How can I do this?** (Preferably without running Node.js app in another port and client in another port, because of pathing and cross-domain issues)

I installed also Yeoman and it's using out of the box grunt-contrib-livereload package, but from what I understood it's using Node.js Connect server for serving client-side files, thus being separated from my Node.js application..

Example from Gruntfile.js generated by Yeoman:

```js
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// ... cut some parts
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        livereload: {
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*/*.html',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/*.css',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}'
            ],
            tasks: ['livereload']
        }
        // ..cut some parts
    },
    connect: {
        livereload: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        lrSnippet,
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, 'app')
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ..cut some parts
});

grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'clean:server',
    'coffee:dist',
    'compass:server',
    'livereload-start',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open',
    'watch'
]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you have solved this question yet, but I have done this by adding my express application as a middleware attached to the 'connect.livereload.options.middleware' option.

However, automatic reloading of server side code doesn't work. For that you could implement a reload friendly server using a simple 'node ./server.js', create a connect middleware that acts as a transparent proxy to your development server, and invoke that within your Gruntfile.js before your standard connect/livereload server starts.

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                    lrSnippet,
                    mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                    mountFolder(connect, 'app'),
                    require('./server') // your server packaged as a nodejs module
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
var app = express();

...
// Export your server object.
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Do you set up your server in server.js like http.createServer(app).listen(8080)? If you do, and access the app through localhost:8080 it wouldn't live reload client files, right? But if you would access localhost:9000 it would, but then again the node.js application isn't answering from there.. or am I doing it wrong? :)

Comment: No I don't setup an http.createServer(app). I use module.exports = app and when I do a require('./server') it returns 'app', which is an express app (every express app is a connect middleware).

I just access the entire app on http://localhost:9000.

Comment: It's fairly hackish, But I was able to get nodejs + connect/livereload + grunt to play nicely.

https://github.com/sheenobu/yo-nodejs-example/commit/663509d7d7e41004c402e322292a9a4b14122002

Comment: Ahh, you're correct! Though, I just have to create server in the "server.js" since I'm using also socket.io, happen to have any medicine for that?

Comment: hrm. One option might be to separate out your socket.io stuff and your express http server stuff. 

Then, you can write a grunt task which starts the your socket.io on a separate port.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is using `Gulp` that I am more familiar with, instead of Grunt, but I imagine the same approach would work with `Grunt` as well.

See [my repository](https://github.com/dmitriz/min-server) (and [an older one](https://github.com/dmitriz/gulp-automation)) and [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729776/1614973).

*Neither any browser extension nor adding any script to your files is needed*.

The solution is based on the [`gulp-livereload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload) and [`connect-livereload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-livereload) packages working together. First, you start your *live reload listener*, and pipe into it any file changes (change `*` to any more specific [`node-glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) to listen to only specific files):

```
var gulpLivereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulpLivereload.listen();

gulp.watch('*', function(file) {
  gulp.src(file.path)
    .pipe(gulpLivereload());
});
```

Second, you configure your server to use the *listener* as middleware via `connect-livereload`:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var connectLivereload = require('connect-livereload');

connect()
  .use(connectLivereload())
  .use(connect.static(__dirname))
  .listen(8080);
```

See the packages for more information on how they work internally.

Answer (score 0):

In the Gruntfile, remove `connect:livereload` and `open` from `server` task.

Add following script in the HTML file

```
<!-- livereload script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script src="http://'
        + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0]
        + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')
</script>
```