# LiveReload with Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I've consulted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430183/1388017) as a starting point, in addition to the [watch github page](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload).

My watch task looks like this:

```
watch: {
  less: {
    files: ['less/**/*.less'],
    tasks: ['less'],
    options: {
      livereload: true
    }
  },
  handlebars: {
    files: ['templates/**/*.hbs'],
    tasks: ['handlebars'],
    options: {
      livereload: true
    }
  }
}
```

First I tried with the browser extension, and then later I added this script (and verified that it is loaded) in my index.html

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

I also tried adding this to my watch js:

```
livereload: {
  files: ['dev/**/*'],
  options: {
    livereload: true
  }
}
```

I also have a connect task, and I've tried running grunt with or without it to no avail.

```
connect: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      port: 35729
    }
  }
}
```

And still no live-reload...

Comment: What's the exact command you use for launching?

Answer (score 1):

this is my Gruntfile.js and my connect version is 0.9.0, this config can use for different  livereroad  port

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
        demo: {
            files: ['web/*.*'],
            options: {
                livereload: 5000
            }
        },
        dev:{
            files: ['web1/*.*'],
            options: {
                livereload: 3030
            }
        }
    },
    connect: {
        demo: {
            options: {
                base: "web",
                port: 1111,
                hostname: '*',
                livereload: 5000,
                open: {
                    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:1111'
                }
            }
        },
        dev:{
            options: {
                base: "web1",
                port: 2222,
                hostname: '*',
                livereload: 3030,
                open: {
                    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:2222'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
grunt.registerTask('demo', ['connect:demo', 'watch:demo']);
grunt.registerTask('dev',['connect:dev','watch:dev']);
```

}

Comment: thank you for tip，this is my first answer in stackoverflow，I find this problem only in my chrome ， it can change port succes in mac10.10 safari and websocket is work fine

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
watch: {
  options: { livereload: true },
  less: {
    files: ['less/**/*.less'],
    tasks: ['less']
  },
  //...
}
```

Also try running in verbose mode (`grunt do-something -v`) to check that the livereload server starts and that the port is correct.

Comment: Your js is exactly the same as my js, but the -v tip is kinda cool

Comment: It's not exactly the same, the difference was putting the options at the root of the watch object.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue only with sass compilation instead of less. When i used the -v switch i can see that the Live reload server has been started on port 35729. When i make a change to one of the sass files the page reloads but nothing happens. Interestingly the output says: **Live reloading style\v4\sass\_core\_salvaged.scss...**
So it looks like it is sending the changed scss file to the live reload server rather than the generated css file. How do i change this?

Answer (score 0):

Watch has worked for me out of the box, without livereload.  Have you tried removing the livereload options and the script include?

Then: grunt; grunt watch

(the default task does the build, then watch keeps an eye out for changes)